# Rendering 2D image using Direct3D

Tags: winapi, directx, gdi+, direct3d, direct2d

I am trying to replace my GDIPlus rendering with Direct3D. I am rendering some large images of the order (10K x 10K) and it gets really slow with GDI. I am now rendering the image as texture onto a Quad using Direct3D. The image does render but the quality is really off when the image is zoomed out.

I am using the following filters.

```
m_pDevice3D->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
m_pDevice3D->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
//m_pDevice3D->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAXANISOTROPY, 4);
m_pDevice3D->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
```

I have already tried rendering using Anisotropic filter already with no significant improvement.

Comment: screenshots might help?

Answer (score 1):

You can not render a large image on a small surface with a good quality without paying the price of an extensive filtering.

This is a signal processing issue named aliasing. To reproduce a signal, you need a medium that has at least twice the resolution or the spectrum will fold on itself.

In 3D rendering, the typical way to do it is by generating a mipchain. It consists of pre filtered version of the image dividing the resolution by two until we reach a size of 1x1. The GPU is then able to pick the proper version.

If your image is dynamic, and you know the display area, you will prefer a runtime filtering, but to do that with a GPU, you will have to recent direct x version with shaders or work with temporary offscreen surface to ping pong the reduction step by step.

Comment: Hi, I'm not direct3d expert, can you please tell what is ping pong surfaces and how can I do this? I'm currently working on cuda decode sample and it works fine but the docs says it's not optimize, and it says "For optimal performance, use two or more D3D9 surfaces to ping/pong between them. This allows the driver to work on both decode and display without waiting." I searched and found your answer, but I still don't know what is this ping/pong thing.

Comment: ping pong techniques are a corner stone of many system, like post processing in a render engine. The principle is trivial, you have two surfaces and you are alternating usage from render target to texture, reading A and writing B, then reading B and writing A, and so on… For the original poster, to apply in one unique step a large high quality up-scaling, doing it in steps may simplify the problem ( and in that case, you have a chain of ping pong surface of increasing sizes if you don't want to mess with viewport )

Comment: @Hamed Things are a little busy at the end of year, but this is what SO is made for :) Also, worth to say that ping pong is usually necessary because you can't read and write in place a resource. This was true, but not anymore for compute shaders and their RWBuffers and RWTextures.

Comment: I see, I will try this method today the way you said. I think I got what should I do now. Thanks again!

Comment: I did what you said and it's working way better now, thanks for your help.